# Python, import a modulo from a father directory

Tags: python, import, module

I want to know how import a file that is one level up.
I read in google this:

```
>>> sys.path.append("../")
```

But I dont like it and i hope there are a better solution

Comment: That is how filesystems are working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option, if what you are writing is part of a package, is to use relative imports like so:

```
from .. import foo
```

where `foo` is the name of the module you're trying to import.

Similarly, if you've got another module in the current directory, you can use:

```
from . import bar
```

Sadly (or perhaps not so sadly), though, this doesn't extend any further than this.  You can't go up to a grandparent, or higher.

**EDIT**:

As so graciously pointed out by JAB, my last comment there is not true:

> from ...sys import path
>
> Note that while that last case is legal, it is certainly discouraged ("insane" was the word Guido used).

I must have internalized Guido's description of it too much. ;^)

**EDIT**:

Okay, I just verified this in 2.7 - this apparently goes as deep as you like, and is dependent on the number of `.`

```
from .... import greatgrandparent
```

works juuuust fine.  I think I'm going to need [a bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr_Creosote)

Comment: "You can't go up to a grandparent, or higher." PEP 328 seems to imply that you can. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision

Comment: And I just confirmed that you can (in Python 3, at least; it shouldn't make a difference with Python 2, as this relative import syntax was implemented in one of the versions of that first).

Comment: "I must have internalized Guido's description of it too much. ;^)" Wasn't Guido's description there referring to the usage of relative import syntax to import an item from a standard Python module? (I mean, it would be pretty silly to do a relative import to get something from a built-in Python module when it makes much more sense and is more logical to just do an absolute import for those.)

Comment: Would you look at the trouble my jokes get me in?  I guess I just read too quickly.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm that `from .... import greatgrandparent` works? I'd like to get away from this kind of thing `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..', '..')))`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how your project is organized you may be able to import it normally. Lets say your project structure is like this:

```
/tmp/test_prj/launcher.py
/tmp/test_prj/mymodule/__init__.py
/tmp/test_prj/mymodule/helper.py
/tmp/test_prj/mymodule/mysubmodule/__init__.py
```

If you use a launcher (`launcher.py` in this case) and always calls your project with `./launcher.py` you may import `helper.py` inside `mysubmodule` using the following line:

```
from mymodule import helper
```

This works because your current working directory is `/tmp/test_prj`. You can check it with `print sys.path`, it should be the first one.

Let me know if I wasn't clear enough :D